# How to upload image to firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a input type = "file" in my html, and i am trying to upload a image to firebase and I done with the below code and its currently not working. "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'sem' before initialization  at upload" What am I missing? Answers welcomed.

```
const img_upload = document.querySelector('#img');
img_upload.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
});
const sem = document.querySelector("#sem");
function upload(){
    const num = document.querySelector("#imgsave").value;
    var storageRef = storage.ref(num+'/'+sem.value);
    var uploadTask = storageRef.put(selectedFile);
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
    }, function(error){
        console.log("error");
    }, function(){
        window.alert("Certificate Uploaded Successfully");
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have an element in your page which corresponds to the `sem`selector?

Comment: Yes, there's the particular element. I found that to be working when i brought everything under the function upload() and making some modifications to the img_upload thing.Thank You.